# proper form for sm.ancova

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a non-parametric ANCOVA with a Tukey-Kramer post hoc. It was suggested to me that `sm.ancova` could do this but the help sheet of this proc is confusing. What is the "group" function?
I have four sites measured over multiple years. Year is my co-variate.

Statistical questions I'm addressing: 
Main effects: 1) are the slopes different?
Post-hoc: 2) which sites are different from each other?

any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm so lost with this thing.

current code that does not work:

```
   data1
    library(sm)
    attach(data1)
    x<-year
    x
    y<-c(data1[,2:5])
    y
    as.vector(y)
    sm.ancova(x,y,group=x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sm.ancova(year,data,site)
```

I believe `group` is your independent variable so in this case your sites (or treatment group).

You also need to specify model as equal or parallel.